# MKMapView Detects If There Is POI At Tapped Coordinate

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit

Is it possible to detect if the users tapped on a POI on MKMapView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Apple doesn't expose their POI layer (if you are talking about `-[MKMapView showsPointsOfInterest]`) since this is their own proprietary data. You could detect taps on the map, but you have no way to correlate to the data being rendered.

Comment: The new iOS does this feature. I'm still trying to figure this out please help